# How on Earth has this question been marked as duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

My question has been marked as a duplicate: 
[Why did Voldemort need to drink Unicorn blood?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67034/why-did-voldemort-need-to-drink-unicorn-blood)

The other question is very generic and is by no means related to my question.

Please explain the close votes.

Comment: Sachin, I misread your question and did a binding VTC. I was wrong and I apologize. It wasn't until after I had done the VTC that I got to thinking about your question and the Horcrux aspect of it. Anyhow, @DVK has taken care of it, and, again, I do apologize for misreading. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess It's alright. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - Join me! Together, we will rule the HP Galaxy!

Comment: Join me or you'll die?

Comment: @DVK - Well, how can I say no to that? :D (I get to be in charge of all unicorn blood. And Horklumps. Don't forget about the Horklumps!)

Comment: @Slytherincess - the ability to unilaterally close a question is insignificant next to the power of Horklumps!

Comment: @DVK - Exactly! See, you always get where I'm coming from :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have cast a binding VTRO on this (to undo @Slytherincess' binding VTC) since I don't think any of the answers on the linked question answer the main point of the question:

The Horcruxes **already** were keeping Voldemort alive (or at least undead). Why did he need the Unicorn blood (when he existed without it prior to residing in Quirrell's head in Hogwarts, and presumably, since Quirrell died till V. obtained a new body in GoF).

Comment: Yes, this. Thanks for taking care of Sachin's question :)

Answer (score -1):

I've voted to keep it closed. Several of the answers to the question about the [potential uses of unicorn blood](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8889/what-are-the-uses-of-unicorns-in-harry-potter) relate to the reason why Voldemort was drinking unicorn blood.

Since A completely encompasses B, B is a duplicate.

Comment: Voldemort was already not dead prior to ever coming across unicorns in HP1. So those answers don't actually answer the question (you're welcome to present a quote from one of the answers as evidence I'm wrong, in which case I'll VTC it)

Comment: @DVK - The fact that the available answers don't answer Sachin's question doesn't make it not a duplicate. If he rephrased the question to avoid asking specifically about unicorn blood, then the focus would probably be clearer

Comment: AFAIR, the fact that a VERY VERY generic question may possibly ask a very specific question, but doesn't; does not qualify as a duplicate. Can't find a Meta on the topic though.